# How to disable "save page as" using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I disable the "save page as" on popup menu and file menu in a web browser ?

Comment: You can't. Next to that, you shouldn't. If you feel that you need to do, search the problem on your side, not on the users side.

Answer (score 8):

You can't mess-up with the client browser settings in javascript without his permissions.

Comment: so what the solution..
that the client browser forbidden to save my web page??

Comment: @nova: You can't. If you send it to the client, he already has it.

Comment: There is **no solution**.  If a browser can access your page, it can save your page.

Comment: @nova7foldism, no solution => that's why you should never store any sensitive information into the markup and javascript. Because no matter how hard you try the client will always be able to see it and save it. You already sent it to the client :-)

Comment: furthermore, your browser probably **already** saved your page in its cache.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Well, technically you *could* disable right-click (context) menus completely by trapping `window.oncontextmenu` which in jQuery is as trivial as:

```
$(window).bind('contextmenu', false);
```

but you shouldn't because it'll just annoy your users and they'll still be able to use the `File->Save Page As...` menu.

Comment: It seems like `$(window).bind('contextmenu', false)` suffices.

Comment: So a popup w/o having the menu + the disabled contextmenu would do it? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't, but there is actually a technical way to prevent file savings of your website via javascript. However it has a lot of problems, but it's simple to explain:

After your webpage's HTML has been transferred from the server into the browser, a javascript routine takes care to extend the contents of the document about the technical file-size limit of the system the browser is running on.

When the user wants to save the file, the file-system will give an error in the moment the file-size maximum limit has been triggered.

However as before the file-saving action will come into place, most often such scripts hit the memory limit of the browser already. That means, you actually already prevent the user from saving the page because the browser denies to handle it any longer. Either by giving a warning message or by just crashing.

So it depends a bit how far you want to go.